# how to get screenshot of Android using adbkit

Tags: android, node.js, adb

I am using Node js to get the image which is displayed on the Android phone screen.

Using [adbkit](https://github.com/openstf/adbkit), I was able to get the ID of the device and establish connection (the phone is usb connected to the computer - windows)

Here is the function that ought to get the image:

```
function get_screen (device_id) {
   client.framebuffer(device_id, 'jpeg', function(data) {
     var png_name = 'png_name_101.jpeg'
     var stream = fs.createWriteStream(png_name)
     data.pipe(stream)
   })
 }
```

Also, I am calling it from:

```
/*
 * @device_id: The serial number of the device.
 *      Corresponds to the device ID in client.listDevices()
 */
 exports.connect_device = function(device_id) {
   client.tcpip(device_id)
        .then(function(port) {
          return client.waitForDevice(device_id).return(port)
        })
        .then(function(port) {
          return client.getDHCPIpAddress(device_id)
            .then(function(ip) {
              return client.connect(ip, port)
            })
            .then(function(id) {
              return client.waitForDevice(id)
            })
            .then(function(id) {
              return client.forward(id, 'tcp:9222',
                        'localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote')
            })
          })
   get_screen(device_id) // <--- here
 }
```

The function succeeds in creating the `jpeg` file, however, its size is 0KB! not what I expected (expected to see a screen-shot!)

P.S. no exception is thrown. GraphicMagick is installed, and the `adb` daemon is up and running.

**How can I get the actual screen in that `jpeg` file?**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to obtain a screenshot by doing this

```
client.framebuffer(device.id, 'jpeg', function(err, data){
    var bufs = [];
    data.on('data', function(chunk){
        bufs.push(chunk);
    });
    data.on('end', function(){
        var buffer = new Buffer.concat(bufs);
        var out = fs.createWriteStream('out.jpg');
        out.write(buffer);
        out.end();
    });
});
```

Both `jpeg` and `png` should be doable.